# javascript's object: Get only the first key of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying currently to get only the first key of an object for my process. It would allow me to make some comparisons with the root of different objects.

currently I use a loop and break at the first instance. Maybe there is more relevant way to achieve this goal?

```js
var objectKey
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};


for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var objectKey=key;        
        break
    }
}

 console.log("the first key is: "  + objectKey)
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: this code works. ask [codereview.se]

Comment: What does "first" mean to you? Object keys [aren't ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/3001761).

Comment: `p.p1` ? .... ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

Then take the *key* from first *index*.

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
var objectKey = Object.keys(p)[0];


 console.log("the first key is: "  + objectKey)
```